# MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getDatabasesPath on channel com.tekartik.sqflite) when building for Windows

Tags: windows, flutter, dart

I am experimenting with using Flutter for a Windows app. All was going fine until I started with a database.

flutter doctor is clean
I have flutter clean and flutter run to no avail.
I notice that when I try to enter in "getDatabasePath" I see two options, so was wondering if it were a conflict there, so added "as sql" to the import and prefixed everything. No good.

```
class Database {
  static final Database instance = Database._init();

  static Database? _database;
  Database._init();
  Future<Database> get database async {
    if (_database != null) return _database!;

    _database = await _initDB('./DataTransfer.db');
    return _database!;
  }
  Future<Database> _initDB(String filePath) async {
    final dbPath = await getDatabasesPath();
    final path = join(dbPath, filePath);
    return await openDatabase(filePath, version: 1, onCreate: _createDB);
  }
```

My dependencies

flutter:
sdk: flutter
window_size:
git:
url: git://github.com/google/flutter-desktop-embedding.git
path: plugins/window_size
ref: 03d957e8b5c99fc83cd4a781031b154ab3de8753
flutter_secure_storage: ^5.0.2
http: ^0.13.4
file_selector_windows: ^0.0.2+1
file_selector: ^0.8.2+1
sqflite: ^2.0.1

Any suggestions? This is the last hurdle in this app and it is a blocker...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, sqflite does not support the windows platform. You can use the "moor" close to it